# Visual Studio - Different Copy Local settings for Different Build Configurations

Tags: copy, local

Been looking online for an answer.
Basically I want the referenced assemblies to have a different "Copy Local" setting depending on the build configuration.

For example:

```
Build: Debug
Assembly: Assembly.dll 
Copy Local: False

Build: Release
Assembly: Assembly.dll
Copy Local: True
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

So far, no, I don't think there's any link between the Copy Local property and the build configuration.

What are you trying to do that requires separate Copy Local properties? Like, what are other differences between Debug and Release configurations?

I'm assuming, but if you *need* a difference because of separate environments, I suggest building/compiling first with Copy Local to True that way your references are copied over. Then turn off Copy Local by setting it to False (you'll be keeping this as a default for your builds now). Switch to the build that needs Copy Local True, then right click the Solution -> Properties -> Build and make sure that the Output path is the one you want. Just be careful that you don't "Clean Solution" or else you'll delete your local copies of the assemblies.